# how to merge two columns and make a new column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, merge

I have to merge two columns in one column that has deferent values
I wrote this code but I can't continue:

```
SELECT Title, ...
FROM BuyItems
```

input:

```
| title |  UK |  US | total |
|-------|-----|-----|-------|
| coca  |  3  |  5  |   8   |
| cake  |  2  |  0  |   2   |
```

output:

```
|title |Origin | Total|
|------|-------|------|
|coca  |  UK   |   3  |
|coca  |  US   |   5  |
|cake  |  US   |   2  |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CROSS APPLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply) and a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to do this:

```
-- EXAMPLE DATA START
WITH BuyItems AS
(   SELECT  x.title, x.UK, x.US
    FROM    (VALUES ('coca', 3, 5), ('cake', 2, 0)) x (title, UK, US)
)
-- EXAMPLE DATA END

SELECT bi.Title, upvt.Origin, upvt.Total
FROM BuyItems AS bi
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('UK', bi.UK), ('US', bi.US)) upvt (Origin, Total)
WHERE upvt.Total <> 0;
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`UNPIVOT` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#unpivot-example):

```
-- EXAMPLE DATA START
WITH BuyItems AS
(   SELECT  x.title, x.UK, x.US
    FROM    (VALUES ('coca', 3, 5), ('cake', 2, 0)) x (title, UK, US)
)
-- EXAMPLE DATA END

SELECT upvt.Title, upvt.Origin, upvt.Total
FROM BuyItems AS bi
UNPIVOT (Total FOR Origin IN (UK, US)) AS upvt
WHERE upvt.Total <> 0;
```

My preference is usually for the former, as it is much more flexible. You can use explicit casting to combine columns of different types, or unpivot multiple columns. `UNPIVOT` works just fine, and there is no reason not to use it, but since `UNPIVOT` works in limited scenarios, and `CROSS APPLY/VALUES` works in all scenarios, I just go for this option as default.

Comment: if it will be mire than 3 rows, we should enter the records like that?

Comment: Just use the bottom part of the query, the top CTE was just to generate some dummy data to give a working example.

Comment: As an aside, how you want your data to be formatted, is how it should be stored in the first place (at least closer to it). You may want to read up on database normalization.

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (t.title, 'UK', uk), (t.title, 'US', us)
     ) v(title, origin, total)
where v.total > 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple unpivot:

```sql
SELECT YT.title,
       V.Origin,
       V.Total
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('UK',UK),
                        ('US',US))V(Origin,Total);
```